# regular expression to find word after a character and before another one if included

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like:

> image/media-group/rugby-league-programme-covers-3436?sort=title

or

> image/media-group/rugby-league-programme-covers-3436

I need to get everything after media-group and not including `?` or anything after.

So in both instances `rugby-league-programme-covers-3436` is what I need to return

I used the regular expression `/media-group/(.*)\?` which works for the instance where there is a query string but not in the instance where there is no query string.

I am using the below code

```
var patt=new RegExp('/media-group/(.*)\?');
return patt.exec(url)[1];
```

Your help on this would be most appreciated

Comment: You need to escape (or double escape in this case) those characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the best pattern would be:

```
/^[^\#\?]+\/media-group\/([^\?]+).*$/
```

which breaks out as:

```
^                 - start of string
[^\#\?]+          - one or more non-hash, non-question-marks
\/                - literal char
media-group       - literal chars
\/                - literal char
(                 - start capture group
  [^\?]+          - one or more chars non-question-marks
)                 - end of capture group
.*                - zero or more chars
$                 - end of string
```

The reason this works is because [^\?]+ is "greedy" in that it will attempt the longest possible match, which encompasses either a question-mark followed by arbitrary chars, or nothing, since all chars to the end of the string have already been captured in the non-question-mark capture group.

So, using

```
var RE=new RegExp(/^[^\#\?]+\/media-group\/([^\?]+).*$/),
    url="image/media-group/rugby-league-programme-covers-3436?sort=title";

console.log(url.match(RE)[1])
```

prints: `rugby-league-programme-covers-3436` and changing url to `image/media-group/rugby-league-programme-covers-3436`, produces the same result.

#### Update

Modified the pattern re David Foerster's comment.

Comment: This breaks, if `/media-group/` appears in the query or fragment part. I suggest `/^[^\?\#]+\/media-group\/([^\?\#]+).*$/` instead. Still a good answer.

Comment: Inside a character class, you don't need to escape `#` and `?`, or any special characters except `\ `. `^`, `]`, and `-` might also need escaping, depending on where you place them inside the character class.  In other words, `/^[^#?]+\/media-group\/([^?]+).*$/` will work just fine.  See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: How would you modify this regex to get only the match between "/", for example, if the string is `image/media-group/rugby-league-programme-covers-3436/morestuff/morestuff/` then you'll like to get only `rugby-league-programme-covers-3436`

Comment: @arielcr Umm.. will the match you require ALWAYS be the third element in the path? If so, I wouldn't use a regex. Rather, I'd `path.split('/')[2]`